# Finding and raising a Circular reference error in a import excel file

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, circular-reference

I have an excel document with two columns labelled "Part Number" and "Parent Part Number."
The hierarchy of products and their components is displayed in the excel file.
The "Parent Part Number" of the product should be NULL, while the "Parent Part Number" of the component must exist.
The biggest issue now is that Excel has a circular reference.

ex.

| Part Number | Parent Part Number |
| --- | --- |
| Skateboard | NULL |
| Board | Skateboard |
| Axel | Board |
| Skateboard | Axel (Error) |

or

| Part Number | Parent Part Number |
| --- | --- |
| Skateboard | NULL |
| Board | Skateboard |
| Axel | Board |
| Board | Axel (Error) |
| Car | NULL |
| Board | Car (No issue) |

A hierarchy is now created by a Python pandas script using this table.
First, it locates all products with "Parent Part Number" values of NULL. (level 1)
Then it searches all the components having the 'Parent Part Number' which we found in above level.
And So on. Now if there are circular references (like shown above as 'Error' in table),
The Python should raise a 'Circular Reference Found'.

Please let me know how to create logic for this issue.
Any help is appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of your problem if terms of a graph, with [networkx](/questions/tagged/networkx), you can identify *circular references*.

One option is to use [`networkx.simple_cycles`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html) :

```
import networkx as nx
​
def get_cr(df):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    edges = (df[["Parent Part Number", "Part Number"]]
                 .dropna().to_numpy().tolist())
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    return nx.simple_cycles(G)
​
circulars = get_cr(pd.concat([df1, df2])) # <- pd.concat to test both examples
​
if circulars:
    print("/!\ : Circular references detected!")
    for c in circulars:
        print(f"{c[-1]} -> {' -> '.join(c[:-1])} -> {c[-1]}")
```

​
Output :

```
/!\ : Circular references detected!
Axel -> Skateboard -> Board -> Axel # <- first CR
Axel -> Board -> Axel               # <- second CR
```

Comment: Hey @Timeless, Could you please tell me what df1 and df2 means 9th line ? I did know the 3rd line df is my excel/dataframe but what about the other one ?

Comment: They refer to both of your two _dataframes/examples_. If you have only one, you can use `circulars = get_cr(df)`.

Comment: Thanks @Timeless, the code is working as expected with some small edits like
`def get_cr(df):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    edges = (df[["Parent Part Number", "Part Number"]].dropna().to_numpy().tolist())
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    return nx.simple_cycles(G)

circulars = get_cr(df)

if list(circulars):
    print("Circular references detected!")
`